# Trouble using apt with kali linux system wide proxy

Tags: apt, kali-linux, proxy

Hello I apologize in advance, I am very new to Linux:

To preface, I am using PdaNet+ to use a wifi hotspot which requires me to use a proxy. I'm easily able to configure it into Firefox but I'm unable to do do `sudo apt update`. I am using kali linux live with persistent storage.

I have used the following in the terminal and added it to the bottom of etc/bash.bashrc

```
    export ftp_proxy="ftp://proxyIP:port"
    export http_proxy="http://proxyIP:port"
    export https_proxy="https://proxyIP:port"
    export socks_proxy="https://proxyIP:port"
```

After that im able to do `wget http://www.google.com/` and connect

I then created a file in etc/atp/apt.conf.d and named it 95proxy.conf
I put this code into it:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy"http://proxyIP:port/"; 
Acquire::https::Proxy"http://proxyIP:port/";
Acquire::ftp::Proxy"http://proxyIP:port/";
```

Then I logged out and restarted, I then re-entered the previous code into the terminal.

But when it comes to updating I get:

temporary failure resolving http.kali.org

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: "_I am very new to Linux_" - in that case don't use Kali unless it's a requirement of some course you're taking

Comment: Yes, please use a normal operating system. Kali is not designed to be used as a normal OS, it is not a normal OS, and it is absolutely the worst choice if you want to learn Linux. There are many things that are very easy with normal distributions that are very hard with Kali. For example, Kali has networking disabled which is why you are seeing this problem. Please read https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/ and [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360).

Comment: @terdon thank you for explaining. I will do more research to see what distribution best suits my goals.

Comment: @Tye don't overdo it with the research – the list from that Kali page is "good enough"; start with Ubuntu or debian, and you get a working system that does what you need.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thank you I've decided I'll start leaning debian